# How to iterate over a Python dictionary in defined order?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I'm trying to iterate over a dictionary that I have defined in a specific order, but it always iterates in a different order than what I have defined in my code.  This is just a basic example of what I'm trying to do.  The dictionary I'm iterating over is much larger,  has much more complexly named keys, and is not in alphabetical/numerical order.

```
level_lookup = \
{
'PRIORITY_1' :   { 'level' : 'BAD',   'value' :   ''  },
'PRIORITY_2' :   { 'level' : 'BAD',   'value' :   ''  },
'PRIORITY_3' :   { 'level' : 'BAD',   'value' :   ''  },
'PRIORITY_4' :   { 'level' : 'BAD',   'value' :   ''  },
'PRIORITY_5' :   { 'level' : 'CHECK', 'value' :   ''  },
'PRIORITY_6' :   { 'level' : 'CHECK', 'value' :   ''  },
'PRIORITY_7' :   { 'level' : 'GOOD',  'value' :   ''  },
'PRIORITY_8' :   { 'level' : 'GOOD',  'value' :   ''  },
}

for priority in level_lookup:
    if( level_lookup[ priority ][ 'value' ] == 'TRUE' ):
        set_levels += str( priority ) + '\n'
```

I need the order that I define the dictionary in to be preserved during iteration. My order is not alphabetical, so sorting alphabetically wouldn't really help.  Is there any way to do this? I've tried `level_lookup.items(), but that doesn't maintain my order either.

Comment: If you want to use a regular dictionary in a particular order... [don't](http://blog.amir.rachum.com/post/54458435089/python-hash-id-and-dictionary-order).  Use an `OrderedDict` instead.

Comment: Dictionaries don't have an order. That is, items have to come out in some order when you iterate, but it's whatever is easiest for Python, and may or may not resemble the order in which items were put in, and may change when you add or delete items. If you want your items in an order, use a container that maintains the order of item, such as `collections.OrderedDict`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use an [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). It works exactly the way you want it, however you need to define it that way. Alternatively, you can have a list of keys in order, and iterate through the list and access the dictionary. Something along the lines of:

```
level_lookup_order = ['PRIORITY_1', 'PRIORITY_2', ...]
for key in level_lookup_order:
    if key in level_lookup:
        do_stuff(level_lookup[key])
```

This will be a pain to maintain, though, so I recommend you just use the OrderedDict.

As a last option, you could use 'constants'. Like,

```
PRIORITY_1 = 1
PRIORITY_2 = 2
...
lookup_order = {PRIORITY_1: 42, PRIORITY_2: 24, ...}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're fine with using the key-sorted order:

```
for key in sorted(level_lookup.keys()):
    ...
```

That's what I generally do if the `dict` is provided to me, and not something I instantiate (rather than `OrderedDict`.

Answer (score 4):

You *could* use a `collections.OrderedDict`. If that doesn't work for you, you could sort the keys before you iterate over them:

```
for k in sorted(myDict, lambda k: int(k.rsplit("_",1)[1]):
    # do stuff
```

Note however, that this particular sorting costs linear space and O(nlogn) time. Also, it uses the coincidental numbering system `"PRIORITY_N"` for sorting, which may not always be valid

Answer (score 2):

Try;

```
for priority in sorted(level_lookup.iterkeys()):
```

As Jon has pointed out, `keys()` and `iterkeys()` are redundant here;

```
for priority in sorted(level_lookup):
```

Comment: `iterkeys()` etc... is redundant here... just use `sorted(level_lookup)` - it will work for Python 2 and 3

Comment: Lovely answer.  Not sure why this wasn't the preferred "Correct" answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be better off *not* using a containg dictionary and see no compelling reason to use one in this case. A`list`would store the items in the desired order:

```
level_lookup = [
    {'level': 'BAD',   'value': ''    },
    {'level': 'BAD',   'value': ''    },
    {'level': 'BAD',   'value': ''    },
    {'level': 'BAD',   'value': ''    },
    {'level': 'CHECK', 'value': 'TRUE'},
    {'level': 'CHECK', 'value': 'TRUE'},
    {'level': 'GOOD',  'value': ''    },
    {'level': 'GOOD',  'value': ''    },
]

set_levels = ''
for level, priority in enumerate(level_lookup, start=1):
    if priority['value'] == 'TRUE':
        set_levels += 'PRIORITY_{!s}\n'.format(level)
print set_levels
```

In fact, you could write the whole thing as list comprehension:

```
set_levels = ('\n'.join('PRIORITY_{!s}'.format(level)
                for level, priority in enumerate(level_lookup, start=1)
                    if priority['value'] == 'TRUE'))
print set_levels
```

Comment: This would work, but there are other sections of code that depend on doing dictionary look-ups based on the keys. I could loop through a list, but it's cleaner to maintain this way rather than to loop through a very large list every time you're looking something up when the key is known.