# Plot matching lines from python dictionary

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have several values on two python dictionaries (for example), and I want to plot them with matplotlib matching the keys.

For example, imagine I have these dictionaries:

```
dic1 = {
    "1":1,
    "2":2,
    "3":3,
    "4":4
}
dic2 = {
    "3":3
    "4":4
}
```

If I try to plot them, the line of the second dictionary would start at the beginning of the graphic, and I don't want that. I've seen approaches with histograms, but I need the plot to be a lines plot.

I hope I expressed myself correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you'd like to create a line chart contained multiple lines. This is what I would do

```
# Import Library
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')

# Prepare canvas
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()

# Load data
dic1 = {"1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3, "4": 4}
dic2 = {"3": 3, "4": 4}

# Draw
plt.plot(dic1.keys(), dic1.values())
plt.plot(dic2.keys(), dic2.values())
plt.show()
```

**Result:**

Anyway, based on your data. There will be overlaps.

[image]

But it will work fine if the data is changed.

```
dic1 = {"1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3, "4": 4}
dic2 = {"3": 2, "4": 3}
```

[image]

Comment: Be aware that the x-ticks generated by this code are strings, not numeric values. You would get the same graph appearance (straight line) with `dic1 = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4}`, or `dic1 = {"1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3, "9": 4}`.

Comment: Also, the iteration order over dictionary keys is not specified (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683151/how-to-iterate-over-a-python-dictionary-in-defined-order), so the resulting plot might be random. (I believe Python 3 outputs keys in a deterministic order, but not Python 2). Short story, using dicts for ordered data is a bad idea.